# Material Icons are taking too much time to load in flutter in android studio

Tags: flutter, icons, google-material-icons, flutter-material

When I try to add material icons in the flutter it takes a lot of time to load the suggestion pannel. How can I solve this?

This is the kind of suggestion I am looking fo

[image]

Comment: Can you include your flutter version?

Answer (score 0):

In flutter earlier 2.5 stable versions I have also faced this issue. now I have latest versions 2.10... from this I have not facing this issue. better you can upgrade your versions and check..

From the below material icons library link you can search whatever icon you want with image representation and use it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html